# How to remove static properties from Session

Tags: c#, asp.net

In ASP.NET application, we have a `SessionManager` class, in `SessionManager` class we have declared some static and non static properties. After assigning the values of all the declared properties finally we added `SessionManger` class in Session, and on logout we have just called `Session.Abandon()` method. Is that release static properties or we need to forcefully clear all the static properties? What's the best approach? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not clearly understading what you mean by "static properties".

Comment: For example, Person class have many properties, we make a static property of a Person class and assigned values of properteis and added in Session. Is that static class release their resources on calling Session.Abandon()?

Comment: Could you show a single use case of your `Person` class? Just some lines of code describing what you have just written.

Comment: private static Person _person;
        public static Person Person
        {
            get { return _person; }
            set { _person = value; }
        }

        Session.Add("Person", Person);

Comment: These are not "static properties", they are values stored in the session state.

Comment: @AbuSufyan: Rather than describing your code why not add it to the question if it is relevant (you should find an edit link just underneath).

Comment: Thanks, @Chirs. I've modified my question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by "static properties" you mean the values stored in session then this is exactly what that method call does. From the MSDN documentation:

> The Abandon method destroys all the objects stored in a Session object and releases their resources.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524310(v=vs.90).aspx